# Python's equivalent of Typescript's Parameters utility type?

Tags: python, python-typing

Imagine a library like:

```
class FooSdk:
   def __init__(config_a: something, config_b: something_else, **kwargs):
     pass # ...
```

And you have your own utility function like:

```
def do_something_with_foo(foo_config, another_argument: List):
    temp_foo = FooSdk(**foo_config)
    # ... do something with another_arguemnt and temp_foo
```

Is there any way to add typing to `foo_config` to align it with `FooSdk.__init__`'s call signature?  This would be like `ConstructorParameters` in Typescript - see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype)

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.8, we have access to [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) as proposed by [PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/).

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: str) -> None:
        pass

class FooInit(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: str

def construct_foo(foo_init: FooInit) -> Foo:
    return Foo(**foo_init)
```

Unfortunately there is no way to simply "copy" the `__init__` signature and create a `TypedDict` class from it. (Not in a way that static type checkers will understand, anyway.) So you'll have to define it manually.

Starting with Python 3.11, `TypedDict` supports usage of the [`NotRequired`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NotRequired) annotation to define optional keys in the dictionary.

---

I think this might be an interesting avenue to pursue. Maybe someone else knows of a proposal to have something comparable to TS `ConstructorParameters` you mentioned.